# How can i unbind for specific jquery scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having scroll event.

```
this.todayScrollerRef = $(window).scroll(() => {
   console.log('some stuff');
});
```

On button click i want to unbind from the event

So when i try

```
$(window).unbind('scroll');
```

it works - and i don't get `some stuff` in console when i am scrolling after the button click.

But because i have another `window.scroll` event i don't want to use `$(window).unbind('scroll');`

because it `unbinds` all of the scroll events.

So i want to unbind specific one - and when i try

```
 $(window).unbind('scroll', this.todayScrollerRef);
```

for my created `todayScrollerRef` reference - it does not work.
Scroll event is not destroyed

I also tried with

```
$(window).on('scroll', this.todayScroller.bind(this));

todayScroller() {
   console.log('some stuff');
}

// on btn click
 $(window).off('scroll', this.todayScroller.bind(this));
```

and it still does not work.

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: could you please provide your second scroll event which you don't need to unbind?

Answer (score 1):

Have your handler like this:

```
this.todayScrollerRef = function() {
  console.log('sd');
};
```

to Bind

```
$( window).bind( "scroll", this.todayScrollerRef );
```

to unbind:

```
$(window).unbind( "scroll", this.todayScrollerRef );
```

Comment: What is the `handler` here ?

Comment: `.bind` is now [deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/bind/). You should use `$(window).on("scroll")` and `$(window).off("scroll")`.

Comment: @JeremyThille i edited my question. I tried that also and it does not work

Comment: What about `.off('scroll')` ? You haven't tried just that.

Comment: @peckoski bind unbind working as expected, check this fiddle:, when you will scroll, you will see, today and tomorrow in console. Now click on remove today button and then scroll, you will see only tomorrow. https://jsfiddle.net/riteshwaghela/3qcfuvpr/8/